# ConstraintLayout - how to keep circle from pushing other views off the page? check minimum dimension?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, shapes

I am trying to set up a layout for a counting app, which has a large circular button slightly above the centre of the screen and a counter display below it. I'm having trouble keeping the circle circular, entirely on the screen, and not overlying the other view in all situations.

The setup I'm currently using is a ConstraintLayout with two TextViews. The button TextView uses an xml oval as its background, and is set to be circular with the "layout_constraintDimensionRatio" attribute set to one. In portrait mode the width is set to 80% of the available space, and all is well when the screen is fairly standard in normal use.

The problem occurs if the available screen dimensions for the app are more square so that the vertical dimension is smaller than the horizontal dimension. In this case the width is still set first so my circle covers the other view or partially slips off screen.

Currently in the landscape layout I have the timer off to one side. Ideally in the landscape layout I would keep the button centred and the counter to the right, but to stop increasing the size of the button if there is not enough space for the timer.

I think that ideally I would set the layout up to check whether the horizontal or the vertical space is shorter initially, then set the smaller dimension first. Is this possible? Or perhaps is there a better approach to achieving my desired layout?

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thank you,
Katie

This is the default xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.CounterFragment">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_background_image"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/dog_image_jpg_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/timer_display"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineHorizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_selector"
        android:contentDescription="@string/counter_button_content_description"
        android:text="@string/counter_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timer_display"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.375"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineVertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the landscape layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.CounterFragment">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_background_image"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/dog_image_jpg_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/timer_display"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/counter_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_selector"
        android:contentDescription="@string/counter_button_content_description"
        android:text="@string/counter_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineHorizontal"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineVertical87"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guidelineVertical12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineHorizontal" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineVertical75"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineVertical12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.125" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineVertical87"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.875" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: portrait layout]
[image: landscape layout]
[image: split screen portrait]
[image: split screen landscape]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest, the primary issue with your layout is the percentage width/height set at 80% and driving the rest of the layout. You are losing control of the circle height and nothing keeps it from growing to cover other views.

Take a look at *ConstraintLayout* [chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Chains). They are a powerful tool and will let you tie your views together so they don't trounce one another. They will help you solve the overlay problem.

You will still want to set the width of the circle to 80% of the width or height depending on the orientation of the device. I assume that you want the side margins to be such that the circle can be 80% of the view but will allow the circle to be smaller if it needs to fit the screen and not overlap the other views. One way to do this is to define two *Space* widgets that are 10% of the layout width and 10% high. Place one in the upper left corner of the layout and the other in the lower right. Constrain the circle to these *Space* widgets on the left, top and right. Place the circle in a vertical chain with the *TextView* below.

Here is a mock up of what it would look like. You will have to work with your layout to get it right, but these are some concepts that should help. (Is seems to me that this can also be done without the *Space* widgets, but that solution is not occurring to me right now. I'll post back if it dawns on me.)

The XML follows the GIF.

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/timer_display"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/counter_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="@string/counter_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timer_display"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spaceBottomRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spaceStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spaceStart"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.375"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/spaceBottomRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.10"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.10" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/spaceStart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.10" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the spaces solve the problem perfectly.